# how to bind RelativeSource Self to MultiConverter WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a custom control and want to pass a two dependency properties to a Multi Converter in a setter on the control style. My converter kicks in, but the values are showing as UnsetValues.

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WPFStyles.CustomControls"
                xmlns:con="clr-namespace:WPFStyles.Converters">

<con:PopUpVisibilty x:Key="PopUpVisibility"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:PopUpNotification}">
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="250"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PopUpVisibility}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type custom:PopUpNotification}}" Path="IsOpen"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type custom:PopUpNotification}}" Path="Header"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:PopUpNotification}">
```

Any help on how to pass these properties correctly would be great.

Comment: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` didn't work?

Comment: Wow, I was being rather stupid there it seems, Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect this to work:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PopUpVisibility}">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsOpen"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Header"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: In my experience, the option **Self** does not show up in intellisense, so @user3519506, I don't think you were being stupid.